# Multi-Inquilino com firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-database

Estou começando um sistema web e ele será multi-inquilino, quero fazer usando o database do firebase, mas ainda não encomtrei uma forma de associar um usuário a um inquilino(empresa) para que ele tenha acesso apenas a árvore daquela empresa.
Uso o seguinte método para criar um usuário e autenticá-lo:

```
// Criar novo usuário
createUserButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
firebase
    .auth()
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value, passwordId.value)
    .then(function () {
        alert('Bem vindo ' + emailInput.value);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error.code);
        console.error(error.message);
    });
});



// Autenticar com E-mail e Senha
authEmailPassButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value)
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        displayName.innerText = 'Bem vindo, ' + emailInput.value;
        alert('Autenticado ' + emailInput.value);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error.code);
        console.error(error.message);            
    });
});
```

Agora minha pergunta é como faço para que eu consiga adicionar informações personalizadas a um usuário como o Id da empresa para que ele tenha acesso só ao que ele tem permissão.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu recomendaria que você tivesse 2 nós raíz: Empresas e Usuários. Aí quando você tiver um novo inquilino (uma empresa), você gera um novo ID no nó Empresas. E coloca todos os dados dessa empresa nesse nó. A sua base de dados estaria mais ou menos assim:

```
{
    "empresas":{
        "empresaX":{
            //Todos dados da empresa
        },
        "empresaY":{
            //Dados da outra empresa
        }
    },
    "usuarios":{
        "usuario1":{
            "nome":"Rosário",
            "empresa":"empresaX"
        },
        "usuario2":{
            "nome":"Dhouglas",
            "empresa":"empresaY"
        }
    }
}
```

Assim, para definir a regra, você faria:

```
{
    "rules":{
        "empresas":{
            "$idEmpresa":{
                ".read":"root.child('usuarios').child(auth.uid).child('empresa').val() == $idEmpresa",
                ".write":"root.child('usuarios').child(auth.uid).child('empresa').val() == $idEmpresa"
            }
        },
        "usuarios":{
            "$uid":{
                ".read":"$uid == auth.uid",
                ".write":"$uid == auth.uid",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E para ligar o usuário à empresa:

```
createUserButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailInput.value, passwordInput.value)
        .then(function () {
            alert('Bem vindo ' + emailInput.value);
            var userLogado = firebase.auth().currentUser; //Pegar o usuario que fez login
            var noUsuarios = firebase.database().ref('usuarios');  //Aceder ao nó usuários da BD
            noUsuarios.child(userLogado.uid).setValue({        //Guardar os dados desse usuário, usando o uid como chave
                email: userLogado.email,
                empresa: "Empresa XYZ",
                cpf: "CPF aqui"
            });
        })     
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error.code);
            console.error(error.message);
        });
});
```

Comment: Percebi que você é iniciante no Firebase. Recomendo que leia a [documentação da Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start?hl=pt-br)